# Posting to back-end with angular and node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, post

Im trying to post to my back-end (Node), that will then take the data and process it with a function.

However I am having problems with my Angular post. When I post with `postman` My console shows

```
{ LoginEmail: 'email@email.com' }
```

This works well and is then sorted with my node.

However posting with my Angular I get

```
{ '{"LoginEmail":"email@email.com"}': '' }
```

This is causing problems with my node processing the data. How can I get it to post the data the same as `postman` sends the data.

My angular view and controller

**View**

```
<form class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2"
              ng-controller="LoginController"
              ng-submit="LoginForm()">
            <div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email*</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control col-sm-12" name="LoginEmail" placeholder="Enter valid E-mail"
                           ng-model="formData.LoginEmail">
                </div>

                <input type="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Controller**

```
FirstModule.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.LoginForm = function () {
        var data = {
            LoginEmail: $scope.formData.LoginEmail
        };

    $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/back-end/test',
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.formData = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        $scope.formData = status;
    });
}
});
```

Part of my back end node

**Node**

```
var firstFunction = function () {
    return new Promise (function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            app.post('/back-end/test', function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.body);
                var login = req.body.LoginEmail;
                res.send(login);
                resolve({
                    data_login_email: login
                });
            });
            console.error("First done");
        }, 2000);
    });
};
```

Comment: Try changing the 'Content-Type' to 'application/json'

Comment: Your a star, thanks man. I rebuilt that form 3 times trying to solve that